# Analytic continuation of spline wavelets (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, analytic-continuation

I would like to extend (cubic or higher degrees) [spline wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_wavelet) to complex domain. First, does this continuation exist? Second, I appreciate it if anyone could point me to some references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An overview with pointers to the literature is [Complex B-splines](https://www.ee.cuhk.edu.hk/~tblu/monsite/pdfs/forster0601.pdf), by Forster, Blu, and Unser; see page 262.

One recent application is
[Parameter characterization of complex wavelets and its use in 3D reconstruction,](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-62434-1_38) by Lopez et al.